# How to automatically run commands on SSH login?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos

Whenever I login to my Linux server I'd like to have several commands run automatically (set some variables, change location, etc.)

This needs to be done on user login, not on system start.

How can I set it to do this?

Comment: You need to read the section INVOCATION in bash(1) (`man bash`).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Put the commands in `~/.bashrc`. Anything in there is executed each time you log in.

If you need commands to only run when logging in via ssh (but not when logging in physically), you could probably test for the presence of the `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable, and only run the commands if you find it exists.

Comment: I'm not logging in as root, it's an AWS server so I have to login as "ec2-user" then change to root using "sudo su -". So should I put the commands in "/home/ec2-user/.bashrc"?

Comment: This assumes ~/.bashrc is sourced from your ~/.bash_profile. ~/.bash_profile will be the script that is invoked for a login shell like ssh. I believe ~/.bashrc will get called if you open up a Gnome Terminal, for example, AFTER having already logged in.

Comment: You've confused me, let me explain more: This is an Amazon Web Services instance, which is a virtually server, so no one will ever physically log in (I'm not even sure if it physically exists as one machine). I login using PUTTY with the username ec2-user. This drops me in /home/ec2-user directory. I then change to root user by typing "sudo su -", which then drops me into "/root", then I have to type a series of commands, including changing me back to "/home/ec2-user" and setting some variables, aliases, etc. So... how would I get it to do this?

Comment: Also, since I am changing user, I expect that in the ec2-user bash profile I should put only "sudo su -", and then the rest of the commands in the root bash file?

Comment: NOTE: actually, it's .profile that gets called if it exists, unless .bash_profile, exists, then it is called instead.

Comment: First of all, I would recommend putting "sudo" in front of commands that require it, rather than switching to root.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4795/discussion-between-dgrant-and-alasdair)

Comment: When you run "su - " it provides a "login shell" a shell as if root had logged in directly. I assume this means it will run the .profile/.bash_profile/.bashrc scripts for root, and remove any of the stuff that was set in the user's .profile/.bash_profile/.bashrc. I haven't used "su - " before, but people use it a lot, and that's what the man page implies it does.

Comment: Might be worth noting that you can also put the commands in `/etc/profile` to run it for any user.

Comment: SSH_CONNECTION is also set when using scp, leading to a warning, how could I avoid that?

Comment: self answer: check shell interactivity instead https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch

Answer (score 29):

Just put this in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` if you want this for all users:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]] ; then
    echo "I am logged in remotely"
fi
```

Comment: and how do I lose the session after closing execution?

Comment: @WHK What do you mean by losing the session?

Comment: @Llamageddon: I think he's wondering the same thing I am.  If I wanted to put my entire SSH session into `screen`, I might use your answer and put `screen` there instead of the echo. The problem with that is that finishing the screen session will return to the SSH prompt instead of logging out.  Just writing out this comment gave me the answer, though: add the `logout` command after the `screen` command.

Comment: This however does not work for ssh session which do not use bash, e.g. when I open an sftp session.

Comment: @zondo @e-info128 `exec command` will replace the current shell with whatever you run.

Comment: `.bashrc` is a rather poor place for such commands: they will be run again and again in every new instance of `bash` that you run.

Answer (score 21):

Alternatively, you can specify a command to be run during the invocation of `ssh`:

```
$ ssh -t server 'cmd; exec bash -l'
```

The last command in the list should start an interactive session in your preferred shell. If you have a lot of commands to run, consider creating a script file on your SSH server.

Comment: THIS is very useful. Not sure if it's exactly the answer the questioner asked, but people should know about it, since it may not be obvious. For example "ssh user@host "export x=5; bash"  Then in terminal that pops up echo $x displays 5.

Answer (score 17):

Actually `~/.ssh/rc` is a right place for you to add command to run when **you** log in, rather than any user of the system.

```
 ~/.ssh/rc
         Commands in this file are executed by ssh when the user logs in,
         just before the user's shell (or command) is started.  See the
         sshd(8) manual page for more information.
```

Comment: Not necessarily. It is *a* location where commands can be placed.

Comment: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch08_04.htm

Comment: That could REALLY get someone into trouble if they didn't know what they are doing. It's potentially useful in corner cases, but that could *REALLY* mess someone up if they forgot they put commands there or the name and the path of that file.  Gennerally it would be highly preferred to put the startup login commands in the expected place, .bashrc on the remote side and test for $SSH_CONNECTION, as other answers here have suggested.

Answer (score 6):

If you use a SSH `config` file to connect, you can embed a startup command that will only execute when **you** connect the host.

For this insert / edit the following into your `~/.ssh/config` on your client machine:

```
Host myhost
  HostName *.*.*.*
  User root
  RequestTTY force
  RemoteCommand cd / && bash -i
```

Put the appropriate hostname and append a new line `Port XX` if the port differs from 22. The sample will `cd` in the root of the server. `&& bash -i` and `RequestTTY force` are essential to continue usage of the remote terminal.

To connect to your host you have to install your public key on the target machine that you can retrieve like so:

```sh
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And install on the remote like so:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && echo "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then you can simply connect the machine like so:

```sh
ssh myhost
```

And it will connect and execute the `RemoteCommand`.

Comment: To copy keys to the remote server, it's much easier to use `ssh-copy-id -i <path_to_your_keyfile>`.  It will handle all the directory creation and access controls for you.
However, the `ssh-copy-id` command is not available on all systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a script after *any* user logs into your server, you can achieve this by using the `ForceCommand` directive in the [sshd_config](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) file. The `ForceCommand` will run before any user-supplied commands and before they are given access to a shell.

Follow these steps to set it up:

1. Edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file using your preferred text editor. You may need superuser privileges to do this:

   ```bash
   $ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
2. Add the following lines to the `sshd_config` file:

   ```
   Match User *
       ForceCommand /bin/bash -c "/path/to/script"
   ```

   Some important notes:

   - This will override the process of ssh running the user their shell, so that will have to be added to the script as done below.
   - You can make this user specific by putting the username in place of the star.

Here's an example of what your script could look like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Create a welcome file for the user
touch ~$USER/welcome

# Check if the user is sending a specific command via SSH
if [[ $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ]]; then
    eval "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
else
    # !!NB!!
    # if the user has not specified a ssh command run their shell
    exec $SHELL
fi
```

The script first creates a welcome file in the user's home directory. Then, it checks if the user is sending a specific command via SSH and, if so, executes that command after the script has completed.

**Don't forget to restart your sshd service**
with either `$ sudo systemctl restart sshd.service` or `$ sudo service ssh restart` depending on your system.

Answer (score 0):

To have a script that will execute for any user on login you can add an additional script in:

```
/etc/profile.d/
```

For example:

```
/etc/profile.d/Hello.sh
Hello `whoami`
```

On login would produce:

```
$ ssh MyTestUser@localhost
Hello MyTestUser
```

The profile script is executed as the user that is logging in. This may or may not be a problem depending on what you want the script to do.